# Angular 4/5 passing multiple, non-sequential params using router.navigate?

Tags: angular

I've seen a bunch of answers about how to pass multiple path params when the params are next to each other in the url, for example `user/:userId/:postId`, however in my router I have a route defined as `user/:userId/post/:postId`.  How do I target this route using router.navigate()?

I tried to do `this.router.navigate(['user', userId, postId]);` but this results in matching the catch-all '**' path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, put `post`(string) in between `userId` & `postId`

```
this.router.navigate(['user', userId, 'post', postId]);
```